# How is HttpClient injected into Azure Function app without Startup registration

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, httpclient

I created a new Azure functions project using .net core 3.1 and created a service that has `HttpClient` constructor injected into it like this:

```
public WeatherApiClient(HttpClient httpClient)
{
     _httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

Startup class doesn't have any configuration for HttpClient

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        AddDependencies(builder, config);
    }

    private void AddDependencies(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder, IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IWeatherApiClient, WeatherApiClient>();
    }
}
```

I expect this to not work but when I inject `IWeatherApiClient` in my Functions class it gets injected correctly and has an instance of `HttpClient` injected within it.

Even if I change `IWeatherApiClient` registration from Singleton to Transient, the `HttpClient` seems to be the same instance being injected (verified by checking its Hash code inside `WeatherApiClient`).

How does this work?  Do need the following line in my `AddDependencies` method or not? As it doesn't seem to have any effect vs not having it.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but out of the box some services are already registered for DI. You should check out the `Services` before you weatherclient is added to them. My guess is that where ever you are injecting the weatherclient the DI framework will notice it depends on a httpclient and a registered httpclientfactory will resolve this dependency

Answer (score 1):

Actually you *want* to have the same instance of HttpClient everywhere. As [Microsoft Docu states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), *HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application. Creating a new HttpClient instance per request can exhaust the available sockets.*

If you need to use different instances (the only reason to do so would be ), you can created named HttpClients, e.g.:

```
services.AddHttpClient(Constants.MyClient, (serviceProvider, client) =>
                {
                    var cfg = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
                    var myConfiguration = cfg.GetSection("MySettings");
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(myConfiguration["Domain"]);
                })
```

In this case you would inject `IHttpClientFactory` and call `CreateClient` on it. Now these named instances you have to register explicitelly in the DI.

The line `builder.Services.AddHttpClient();` without parameters does not register HttpClient, but HttpClientFactory in fact, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

So, to sum it up:

- Use builder.Services.AddHttpClient(); this will add the factory
- Inject the factory to your classes
- Create the client from factory, named or not, factory will manage the creation for you

As for why your injection works, I'd guess it is registered elsewhere, e.g. by some package. Function apps from 2.1 version already use DI internally and register logging. Logging with high probability registers HttpClient.